# Aligning multiple div's with "align-items"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was looking for a way to align content within a div with given height and width, some sites suggested flex with "align-items". It works perfectly when all contents have the same hight, but they don't have.

[Here](http://dest.feirell.de/test/06/) is a demo, just hover over the "Player 3 some more info" box and you will see it is pushed down a little.

Can someone tell me how to fix that so it remains in its row and is still centered?

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="column_top_left">
        <div class="row small">
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Datum</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column_top_right">
        <div class="row small">
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Player 1</div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Player 2</div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Player 3<br>some more info</div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Player 4</div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Player 5</div></div>
            <div class="td"><div class="td_wrapper">Player 6</div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="column_bottom_left"></div>
    <div id="column_bottom_right"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.small{
    height: 80px;
}
.big{
    height: 200px;
}
.td_wrapper{
    display:            inline-flex;
    justify-content:    center; /* x align */
    align-items:        center; /* y align */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.td{
    display: inline-block;
    width:              200px;
    height:             100%;
}
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as centering *inside* the `td` items goes, everything you're doing looks great! You just need to style the `td` items themselves a little more. In this case `vertical-align` actually solves the problem.

```
.td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top; /* This is the only change you need! */
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you that brought the change I hoped for ! I will accept this answer in 9 min.